# Navision print through Preview without missing function

Tags: reporting, navision, dynamics-nav

I have a few reports which my customer wants to print through the Preview option. The problem is, that these reports need the CurrReport.Preview function for logging data. But you cannot use this function if you want to print the report.

Is there a possibility to get into the trigger, after the print button in the page preview has been clicked?

Edit to specify: With logging data I mean first the real logging about the prints and secondly options like archive data and other stuff like this.

CurrReport.Preview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301398.aspx

Comment: You haven't detailed what you mean in terms of "logging data" (writing data?). Most writing of data should be done under the data items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to call the Report again using REPORT.Run(Report::"Name Of Report",...) and apply the filters that were used on the initial report.

If it's an intense report it may not be practical (because it has to be run twice), but there are parameters to make the report print automatically;

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355230.aspx

Comment: But where would I put this into? Since I can not find any Trigger for the print button in the preview.

Comment: There is no trigger for the print button. I can't really say exactly where it should go without seeing the report. You'll need to rework the logic of your report to accommodate. You could re-run the report using OnPostReport() and specify a parameter to archive instead.